# Opening 2 Views in a new window

Tags: eclipse, eclipse-plugin, eclipse-rcp, rcp

When the user peforms a certain action from a view i want to open a new window containing extra information. Currently i can open a view in a new window but i can not add a second view below it in the same window.

```
EModelService service = (EModelService) getSite().getService(EModelService.class);

IViewPart topView = getSite().getPage().showView(topid, "secondid", IWorkbenchPage.VIEW_VISIBLE);
MPart topPart = (MPart) topView .getSite().getService(MPart.class);

IViewPart botView = getSite().getPage().showView(botid, "secondid", IWorkbenchPage.VIEW_VISIBLE);                                   
MPart botPart = (MPart) botView.getSite().getService(MPart.class);

service.detach(topPart, 100, 100, 300, 300);     
service.insert(botPart, topPart, EModelService.BELOW, 1f);
```

the top view gets detached and put in a new (trimmed)window but botpart does not get inserted below it into the window.

can anyone tell me why it does not get inserted? Or maybe does someone have some more information about how EModelSerice should be used.

thanks in advance